# Java Spring JPA relationship @OneToMany with third column inside

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have two entities in java (Student and Group) with a `@OneToMany` relationship

```
public class Group {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="name")
private Integer groupName;

public Group(Integer groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "groups_students",
        joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
)
private Set<Student> students;
}
```

And I have a third column `date` in the table `groups_students` on the localhost. `date` is not a field in classes. I need to get this in the `@Query`. Can anyone please help how can I get this (maybe give information to the code about this `date` column or any other ways to)

```
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
}
```

Comment: ok, what query you tried? and can you please add `group_student` entity. You are making it like `manytomany` but trying to use  as `one to may`.

Comment: you can use native query and return Object[], from Object[] you can get "date" or other fields which you want.

Comment: @emotionlessbananas thanks for the response. The code doesn't have this entity. Does it needs? Query is `@Query("SELECT s FROM Group g join g.students s WHERE g.groupName=:gName")` and I need to get `date` with `SELECT`.

Comment: in that case you need to change `@JoinTable` to `@JoinColumn` and need to define a foreign key inside `Student` entity. [Start Here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score 1):

The way of handling additional attributes from the join table is to define that as a separate entity and then split the relation using the intermediate entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups_students")
public class GroupStudent {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Group group;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Student student;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;

    //getter-setter
}
```

Now modify the relationship on the `Group` entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<GroupStudent> groupStudents = new ArrayList<>();
```

And modify also the `Student` entity relation

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<GroupStudent> groupStudents = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now if you want to query the additional attribute like the `date`, you can have a JPQL like this (for example, if you want to get all students of a group where date is in the past)

```
@Query(SELECT s FROM Student s JOIN s.groupStudents gs WHERE gs.group = :group and gs.date < CURRENT_DATE)
```